# Inconsistent results when executing stored procedure in different environments

Tags: sql-server, database, security, stored-procedures

I'm encountering a peculiar issue where a stored procedure returns a number value (as expected) when executed on my local machine, but returns null when executed on the server. Both environments are connected to the same SQL Server database, and the stored procedure in question is designed to log activity and return a newly generated log ID.

The stored procedure `apUserSyncEndPointPollingLogCreate` inserts a row into a table and should return the newly inserted rows' ID.

Here is the relevant part of the stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[apUserSyncEndPointPollingLogCreate] 
    (@UserSync_EndpointPollActivityLogId int OUTPUT,
     @EndpointPollTime DateTime,
     @NumberOfUsersReturned int,
     @EndpointResponse varchar(max),
     @ActivityLogDetails varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblUserSync_EndpointPollActivityLog (EndpointPollTime, NumberOfUsersReturned, EndpointResponse, ActivityLogDetails)
    VALUES (@EndpointPollTime, @NumberOfUsersReturned, @EndpointResponse, @ActivityLogDetails)

    SELECT @UserSync_EndpointPollActivityLogId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

```cs
public int AddEndpointPollActivityLog(DateTime endpointPollTime, int numberOfUsersReturned, string endpointResponse, string activityLogDetails)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionStrings.Alton))
    {
        try
        {
            var p = new DynamicParameters();
            p.Add("@UserSync_EndpointPollActivityLogId", dbType: System.Data.DbType.Int32, direction: System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);
            p.Add("@EndpointPollTime", endpointPollTime);
            p.Add("@NumberOfUsersReturned", numberOfUsersReturned);
            p.Add("@EndpointResponse", endpointResponse);
            p.Add("@ActivityLogDetails", activityLogDetails);

            var result = connection.Query("[dbo].[apUserSyncEndpointPollingLogCreate]", p, commandTimeout: 300, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            int UserSync_EndpointPollActivityLogId = p.Get<int>("@UserSync_EndpointPollActivityLogId");

            return UserSync_EndpointPollActivityLogId;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            // Log SQL exceptions or handle them appropriately
            _logger.LogError("AddEndpointPollActivityLog: SQL Exception occurred: " + ex.Message);
            throw; // Rethrow for higher layers to handle
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log other exceptions or handle them appropriately
            _logger.LogError("AddEndpointPollActivityLog: An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            throw; // Rethrow for higher layers to handle
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the C# code looked like when it worked.

```cs
        public int AddEndpointPollActivityLog(DateTime endpointPollTime, int numberOfUsersReturned, string endpointResponse, string activityLogDetails)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionStrings.Alton))
            {
                var p = new DynamicParameters();
                p.Add("@UserSync_EndpointPollActivityLogId", dbType: System.Data.DbType.Int32, direction: System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);
                p.Add("@EndpointPollTime", endpointPollTime);
                p.Add("@NumberOfUsersReturned", numberOfUsersReturned);
                p.Add("@EndpointResponse", endpointResponse);
                p.Add("@ActivityLogDetails", activityLogDetails);

                var result = connection.Query("[dbo].[apUserSyncEndpointPollingLogCreate]", p, commandTimeout: 300, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                int UserSync_EndpointPollActivityLogId = p.Get<int>("UserSync_EndpointPollActivityLogId");

                return UserSync_EndpointPollActivityLogId;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there an insert trigger on that table in server database?

Comment: No, there is not.  The store procedure returns the value on my local machine, but not on the server. It returns null on the server.

Comment: add SET NOCOUNT ON; at the start of the proc

Comment: Have you compared and reviewed the server and database properties?

Comment: Oh, you read the output parameter, then it probably won't help. I'm guessing you have messed up your environments then

Comment: How do I check the database properties?  I am not a database admin?

Comment: Check if server table has an identity column

Comment: Yes it does. [UserSync_EndpointPollActivityLogId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

Comment: I am using the same database when on my local computer and the server, but it doesn't return a value on the server.

Comment: ok, change your proc so it does: `set  @UserSync_EndpointPollActivityLogId = 666; RETURN(0)` in the beginning and see if it works that way

Comment: It works on my local machine, so I know the syntax is right.

Comment: The proc doesn't seem to be returning query results, just an output parameter. Have you tried using Dapper's `Execute()` method instead of `Query()`?

Comment: That didn't work.  I also looked back to before I changed it and it stopped working and it was Query then also.  Execute works on my machine like Query does, but neither work on the server.

Comment: I added the old code that worked to the bottom of the post.